# Neo4j Causal Clustering, cannot form cluster with existing database

Tags: neo4j

Following the documentation we can set up a cluster with an empty DB.
However, following the instructions to set up a cluster with an existing DB we are met with failure, after 10 minutes all three cores throw an exception.
This could be due to: *causal_clustering.join_catch_up_timeout=10m*
However the databases are already in sync, so "start up should be instantaneous"

Any information pointing us in the right direction would be appreciated.

Exception:

```
2017-01-27 16:28:56.128+0000 INFO  Starting...
2017-01-27 16:28:56.787+0000 INFO  Bolt enabled on 192.168.252.231:7687.
2017-01-27 16:28:56.794+0000 INFO  Initiating metrics...
2017-01-27 16:28:56.885+0000 INFO  Waiting for other members to join cluster before continuing...
2017-01-27 17:00:28.225+0000 ERROR Failed to start Neo4j: Starting Neo4j failed: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@1db1d0b8' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception. Starting Neo4j failed: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@1db1d0b8' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
org.neo4j.server.ServerStartupException: Starting Neo4j failed: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@1db1d0b8' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
        at org.neo4j.server.exception.ServerStartupErrors.translateToServerStartupError(ServerStartupErrors.java:68)
        at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:227)
        at org.neo4j.server.ServerBootstrapper.start(ServerBootstrapper.java:91)
        at org.neo4j.server.ServerBootstrapper.start(ServerBootstrapper.java:68)
        at org.neo4j.server.enterprise.EnterpriseEntryPoint.main(EnterpriseEntryPoint.java:32)
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@1db1d0b8' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:443)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:107)
        at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:199)
        ... 3 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error starting org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory, /var/lib/neo4j/data/databases/graph.db
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.initFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:193)
        at org.neo4j.causalclustering.core.CoreGraphDatabase.<init>(CoreGraphDatabase.java:56)
        at org.neo4j.causalclustering.core.CoreGraphDatabase.<init>(CoreGraphDatabase.java:47)
        at org.neo4j.server.enterprise.EnterpriseNeoServer.lambda$static$2(EnterpriseNeoServer.java:95)
        at org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase.start(LifecycleManagingDatabase.java:89)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:433)
        ... 5 more
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.causalclustering.core.state.CoreState@278df960' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:443)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:107)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.initFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:189)
        ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: This machine failed to get the start state in time.
        at org.neo4j.causalclustering.core.state.CoreState.start(CoreState.java:176)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:433)
        ... 12 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check if the following configurations are in order for your cluster.
1) neo4j.conf
"dbms.connectors.default_advertised_address" for each causal cluster is configured correctly and these IP addresses are reachable to each other.
also, set "dbms.connectors.default_listen_address" to 0.0.0.0
2) unbind the nodes and restart them.

Let me know if you still see the issue.